# Saving a currently opened file without prompts

Tags: c#, filestream, save, save-as

I am experiencing a problem with saving a currently opened file without it popping up the dialog asking what name to save it under.

To clarify myself a little more, I open a .txt file and work with it, then would like to just click 'Save' and it save the file without popping up a 'Save As' dialog box.

Here is my save code:

```
       private void SaveFile()
    {
        SaveFileDialog fileChooser = new SaveFileDialog();
        fileChooser.Title = "Choose Save Location";
        fileChooser.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";

        fileChooser.OverwritePrompt = false; //Removes warning

        DialogResult result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            string fileName = fileChooser.FileName;
            output = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            fileWriter = new StreamWriter(output);

            foreach (Employee emp in employee)
            {
                fileWriter.WriteLine(emp.Firstname + "," + emp.Lastname + "," + emp.Position + "," + emp.Bmonth + "," + emp.Bday + "," + emp.BYear + "," + emp.Salary + "," + emp.Hiremonth + "," + emp.Hireday + "," + emp.Hireyear);
            }

            fileWriter.Close();
            output.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            fileWriter.Close();
            output.Close();
        }
    }
```

Everything works great as far as saving it to a .txt file and loading it back in, it's just that popup that irks me.

Comment: How about if you have the filename already, you skip the fileChooser dialog altogether and just save it? I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: You are specifically showing the file save dialog in your code. If you don't want that... don't do it.

Comment: If I open a file and make changes to it, I would just like to be able to click 'Save' on my toolbar and it save it, rather than it asking what name to save it under.

Comment: then save the `fileName` in a variable - as simple as that

Comment: @Andrew If I remove the dialog code, I receive a 'Stream was not writeable' error. Could this be because I'm not closing my stream prior?

Comment: Figured it out. Simply mistake! Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @Mr Binx: If an answer was helpful to you, please mark it as the correct answer. Otherwise, please add your own answer and mark *that* as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `fileChooser` object is a `SaveFileDialog` object. You're causing it to display by calling:

```
DialogResult result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
```

If you don't want to show the dialog, just omit the `fileChooser` code and instead use:

```
string fileName = strAlreadyKnownFileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd firstly save the full path of the opened file in some variable lets say:

`private string filepath = "path/to/my/file";`

Then you need to create a button and call it i.e. "Save" double click on the button and write this simple code to save whatever you want to the current opened file:

as simple as that...

EDIT:

```
private void SaveFile()
{
   //do your loop and stuff in here and finally write your text to the file using this
   File.WriteAllText(filepath, yourtexttobesaved);
}
```